# How can I append instead of replace text during a search-and-replace with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to do search-and-replace using a regex in Perl.

The text I am searching for is:

```
<space>Number<space>NumberNumberNumber
```

and I want to replace it with:

```
<space>Number<space>NumberNumberNumberI
```

I have the following regex which works in finding the string:

```
\s[0-9]\s[0-9[0-9][0-9]
```

But what do I do about replacing the string? Basically I just want to append an 'I' to the end.

I'm using:

```
perl -pi -e "s/\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]/I/;" testFile
```

but this is replacing the whole thing with I rather than appending to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what backreferences are for.  Just surround the section of text you want to capture with parentheses.  The first set of parentheses are available in $1, the second in $2, and so on.

```
s/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9]{3})/$1I/
```

With Perl 5.10 we gained [named captures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#'%28%3f%3cNAME%3epattern%29'), so you can say

```
s/(?<bodytext>\s[0-9]\s[0-9]{3})/$+{bodytext}I/
```

The stuff inbetween `<` and `>` is the name.  Names become keys in the `%+` variable and the values are the captured text.

Another solution is to use a [zero-width positive look-behinds](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#'%28%3f%3c=pattern%29'-'%5cK')

```
s/(?<=\s[0-9]\s[0-9]{3})/I/
```

or its, new to Perl 5.10, shorthand `\K`

```
s/\s[0-9]\s[0-9]{3}\K/I/
```

---

Try

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/$1I/' filename
```

If you use double quotes the $1 is interpolated by the shell before Perl ever sees it.  If you have problems with something you think should work, it may be a good idea to take a look at what Perl is seeing.  You can do this with [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html):

```
perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e "s/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/$1I/" filename
```

That will produce the following output.

```
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/I/;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

From this we can see that `$1` is missing.  Lets try again with single quotes:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e 's/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/$1I/' filename
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/$1I/;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

And once with escaping:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -pi -e "s/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/\$1I/" filename
BEGIN { $^I = ""; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/$1I/;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
-e syntax OK
```

Comment: that is still replacing the whole thing with I :(

Comment: yeah this is my complete command perl -pi -e "s/(\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/$1I/" testFile.phy

Comment: Ah, you may also have a problem because you are using double quotes instead of single quotes, you either need to escape the $ or use single quotes.

Comment: I live like 10 mins from sterling! should do meetups! :) ...probably not the best place to socialize on SO.  I'll follow you on twitter

Comment: For completeness, you should present the look-behind solution: s/(?<=\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9])/I/ and the new 5.10 \K solution: s/\s[0-9]\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]\K/I/

Comment: @ysth Yeah, I really haven't internalized \K yet.  Still writing too much 5.8 code.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of the answer from 2009 — you can use ***zero-width positive lookbehind assertion***, `(?<=pattern)`, or `\K`, to insert something after your match:

```
%echo "test" | perl -p -e "s/(?<=test)/ing/"
testing
%echo "test" | perl -p -e "s/test\K/ing/"
testing
%
```

Alternatively, to insert something before your match, you'd use ***zero-width positive lookahead assertion***, `(?=pattern)`:

```
%echo "test" | perl -p -e "s/(?=test)/#/"
#test
%
```

Reference:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions