# Using perl to append text to specific lines in a file on Solaris

Tags: perl, append, solaris

I need to append certain strings to specific lines in multiple files.

For instance to replace text in the same way I would use :

```
perl -e "s/trail/rmtrail/g;" -pi /tmp/test/*
```

I can't use sed, because I don't have the -i option on Solaris. But the result i'm trying to obtain with sed would be:

```
sed -i '/rmtrail/ s/$/, fromat release 11.2/' /tmp/test/*
```

Is there a way to do this with perl?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I append instead of replace text during a search-and-replace with Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/933543/how-can-i-append-instead-of-replace-text-during-a-search-and-replace-with-perl)

Comment: ^-- The exact regex is different but the problem and solution are the same.

Comment: I've tried the command, both with single quotes and double quotes. All it does is just replace the string, not append it. The command used was perl -pi -e "s/rmtrail/$1, format release 11.2/" /tmp/test/file1

Comment: What does your `sed` example do (or should do)?

Comment: @robertpas You need parentheses if you want to use `$1`. This is explained at the beginning of the accepted answer to that other question: "Just surround the section of text you want to capture with parentheses. The first set of parentheses are available in `$1`, the second in `$2`, and so on."

Comment: The sed command should look into every file in /tmp/test/, find the line that contains "rmtrail" and append ", format release 11.2" at the end of that line

Comment: Adding paranthesis worked with single quotes. Thank you for the help. Final command: perl -pi -e 's/(rmtrail)/$1, format release 11.2/' /tmp/test/file1

Comment: @robertpas Note, that will only work if `rmtrail` is at the end of the line. [Qtax's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26678002/176646) will work if `rmtrail` is found anywhere in a line (including, for example, `armtrail`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that sed command means to append something to lines which contain `rmtrail` you could do that in a similar way with perl:

```
perl -i -pe '/rmtrail/ && s/$/, format release 11.2/' /tmp/test/*
```